# Chrome Extension: can I make all resources web-accessible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I would like to make all the images used by my extension web accessible in my `manifest.json` without having to list every image separately. I have a large number of images and it would take a long time to list them all.

Is there a way to do this? Can I make an entire folder of images web accessible using the `web_accessible_resources` key?

Comment: why not code generate your manifest.json...

Comment: Simply use a `*.png` pattern for `resources` as shown in the documentation